# how to parse this nested json using gson

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have this json as a string (this is from google custom search). I have made equivalent java classes that are neccessary to parse this. I use gson and am getting a NullPointerException.

```
"items": [
{
"kind": "customsearch#result",
"title": "A Florida Road Trip - Articles | Travel + Leisure",
"htmlTitle": "A \u003cb\u003eFlorida\u003c/b\u003e Road Trip -             \u003cb\u003eArticles\u003c/b\u003e | Travel + Leisure",
"link": "http://www.travelandleisure.com/articles/paradise-usa",
"displayLink": "www.travelandleisure.com",
"snippet": "On a road trip across Florida, Karrie Jacobs goes in search of the   authentic amid   New Urbanist experiments in postmodern nostalgia.",
"htmlSnippet": "On a road trip across \u003cb\u003eFlorida\u003c/b\u003e, Karrie Jacobs goes in search of the authentic amid \u003cbr\u003e  New Urbanist experiments in postmodern nostalgia.",
"cacheId": "QrfYt6p-U3gJ",
"formattedUrl": "www.travelandleisure.com/articles/paradise-usa",
"htmlFormattedUrl":  "www.travelandleisure.com/\u003cb\u003earticles\u003c/b\u003e/paradise-usa",
"pagemap": {
"cse_image": [
  {
   "src":  "http://static0.travelandleisure.com/images/amexpub/0000/6261/200702_urban.jpg"
 }
],
"cse_thumbnail": [
 {
  "width": "160",
  "height": "200",
    "src": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_Jhmej45Lu7L3bQoKz1poITJ5ZeuVvKhH62myfBOj-1VEX9oqwIhvH74"
 }
],
"metatags": [
 {
  "fb:app_id": "145695458805001",
  "og:url": "http://www.travelandleisure.com/articles/paradise-usa",
  "og:site_name": "Travel + Leisure",
  "og:image": "http://static0.travelandleisure.com/images/amexpub/0000/6261/200702_urban.jpg",
  "og:type": "article",
  "og:title": "Driving: Florida’s New Urbanist Experiments",
  "og:description": "On a road trip across Florida, Karrie Jacobs goes in search of the authentic amid New Urbanist exper..."
 }
]
}
}
```

And my equivalent java classes are as follows:

```
public Class Mapper
{
       public Items[] items;
}

public Class Items
{
   public String title;
   public String htmlSnippet;
   public String link;
   public Pagemap pagemap;
}

public Class Pagemap
{
  public Cse_image[] image;
}
public Class Cse_image
{
  public String src;
}
public Class Parser
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //assume json is the string representation of the above json
     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
     Mapper mapper= gson.fromJson(json,Mapper.class);
     System.out.println("src here"+mapper.items[0].pagemap.image[0].src);
  }
}
```

The above code throws me a `NullPointerException` , but if I print till the pagemap ,I get an object with a valid hashcode. Any pointers?

Comment: json code is not valid (http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever dealing with JSON, it is a good practice to use a LINT software to verify the contents of JSON. I recommend using [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com). The JSON list shows multiple errors in the JSON string. Running some REPL cycles here is the corrected JSON.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "customsearch#result",
            "title": "AFloridaRoadTrip-Articles|Travel+Leisure",
            "htmlTitle": "A<b>Florida</b>RoadTrip-<b>Articles</b>|Travel+Leisure",
            "link": "http: //www.travelandleisure.com/articles/paradise-usa",
            "displayLink": "www.travelandleisure.com",
            "snippet": "OnaroadtripacrossFlorida,KarrieJacobsgoesinsearchoftheauthenticamidNewUrbanistexperimentsinpostmodernnostalgia.",
            "htmlSnippet": "Onaroadtripacross<b>Florida</b>,KarrieJacobsgoesinsearchoftheauthenticamid<br>NewUrbanistexperimentsinpostmodernnostalgia.",
            "cacheId": "QrfYt6p-U3gJ",
            "formattedUrl": "www.travelandleisure.com/articles/paradise-usa",
            "htmlFormattedUrl": "www.travelandleisure.com/<b>articles</b>/paradise-usa",
            "pagemap": {
                "cse_image": [
                    {
                        "src": "http: //static0.travelandleisure.com/images/amexpub/0000/6261/200702_urban.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "cse_thumbnail": [
                    {
                        "width": "160",
                        "height": "200",
                        "src": "https: //encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn: ANd9GcR_Jhmej45Lu7L3bQoKz1poITJ5ZeuVvKhH62myfBOj-1VEX9oqwIhvH74"
                    }
                ],
                "metatags": [
                    {
                        "fb: app_id": "145695458805001",
                        "og: url": "http: //www.travelandleisure.com/articles/paradise-usa",
                        "og: site_name": "Travel+Leisure",
                        "og: image": "http: //static0.travelandleisure.com/images/amexpub/0000/6261/200702_urban.jpg",
                        "og: type": "article",
                        "og: title": "Driving: Florida’sNewUrbanistExperiments",
                        "og: description": "OnaroadtripacrossFlorida,KarrieJacobsgoesinsearchoftheauthenticamidNewUrbanistexper..."
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Actually this was a part of the json using google custom search api. I used jsonlint to verify the json on the whole json returned by google custom search api and it was a valid one.

Comment: The JSON that you pasted was wrong, you can check that again, especially missing array specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

First rename your class Cse_Image to a more conventional java name (CseImage maybe?), same for the thumbnail class.

Then you can try genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/.
Put @JsonProperty("cse_image") annotation on your image field (or on your setter/getter if you have) and it works :

```
 Genson genson = new Genson();
 Mapper mapper= genson.deserialize(json,Mapper.class);
 System.out.println("src here"+mapper.items[0].pagemap.image[0].src);
```

Comment: Can you please justify the use of genson and not gson.

Comment: In addition that the code above should solve your problem, genson is faster, does not use only fields but also setter/getters, provides a performant and with small footprint streaming api (since the first release, where gson added streaming support very late around 1.6), has nice features such as its ability to deserialize using ctrs with args (where gson just passes null!), deserialize abstract types/interfaces and many others, have a look a the wiki for a quick introduction